# getting error "index 30 is out of bound, array size is 30" when I try to find unique values out of two arrays in pine script ( Trading View)?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am trying to get unique values out of two arrays, I have coded a function to return the array containing unique values , following is the code I tried

```
disjoint(e,f)=>
    c = e
    d = f
    for i=0 to array.size(e)-1
        for j=0 to array.size(f)-1
            if array.get(e,i) == array.get(f,j)
                array.remove(c,i)
                array.remove(d,i)
    array.concat(c , d)
    finala_array=disjoint(array1,array2)
```

I am passing two arrays (type float) and trying to return a array containing only unique values in pine script but I am getting the following error
**"index 30 is out of bound, array size is 30"**

Need pine coders help in resolving this issue.

Thank you

Comment: i is your outer loop - so you're iterating over it j times. If you have already removed c,i and/or d,i in the inner loop, there is a chance that (if you have duplicated values) that you will again attempt to delete c,i/d,i with in the next iteration of the inner loop

Comment: thank you for quick reply,
can you please help me , how i can remove duplicate values ?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the array is 30 the max index would be 29. Array starts at 0, 1,2,..., 29.

Comment: Hi, I am running both the loop "array.size()-1" , i have already reduced the loop to run for only 29 times